# Collapse FDR value of probes detecting the same gene

Tags: mean, median, fishers-exact-test, microarray

I'm very new in Microarray analysis, so I hope my question wouldn't be too irritating to you all.
I have pre-processed and filtered my microarray datasets and perform differential expression analysis. I would like to note that I do not consolidate my probes.

I have two probes detecting my interested gene, so I have 2 FDR values. I want to collapse them to acquire only 1 FDR value for my gene (and still keep the FDR value of each probe).

In brief, I want to combine two probe FDR values acquired from the same test in the same datasets (I hope I do not make any mistake here)

Would you please suggest me if this is possible and how to do it?

Thank you very much in advance,

Kaj